# How to send and recieve XML data to and from an API service in PHP without cURL

Tags: php, xml

I'm working a project to request data from api service by sending XML data. The programming language used is `PHP`. I have done so much research on the internet and nothing turned up except for using cURL. Is there any other way using PHP to achieve this.

```
<?php
$xml_data = '<mainservice>
               <customer>
                  <appln_id>myid</appln_id>
                  <password>mypasss</password>
                  <cust_id>1234</cust_id>
               </customer>
             </mainservice>';
```

This is the data that needs to be send. The `id` and `password` is for authenticating the API service and `cust_id` for retrieving data of that particular customer.

The Result data is also in XML format.

**NOTE**
The service accepts only POST data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test handle response</title>
    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","URL to Request");
        var xmlDoc;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        var xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><query><author>John Steinbeck</author></query>";
        xmlhttp.send(xml);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must see

https://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Hope you will find your solution.

You can also use this

```
$xml = file_get_contents('post_xml.xml');
$url = 'http://stg.sa.com/post.asmx/';
$post_data = array(
    "xml" => $xml,
);

$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
       'content' => http_build_query($post_data),
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

Comment: thanks for the link. but it only shows reading and printing the XML data received from the web-service. How do I send data in XML format to the web-service using POST.

Comment: I think this is the exactly you want - [link](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-send-receive-xml-data-from-the-server.cfm)

Comment: Thank you. Can you make it as answer, so that i can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Post data using `file_get_contents()` funtion

```
 $xml_data = '<mainservice>
               <customer>
                  <appln_id>myid</appln_id>
                  <password>mypasss</password>
                  <cust_id>1234</cust_id>
               </customer>
             </mainservice>';


$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'xml_data' => $xml_data,
        'var2' => 'abc'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.net/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Get data using file_get_contents() function

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.example.com/test.php?type=menu";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: how does it work with XML? I need to send  `$xml_data = '<mainservice>
               <customer>
                  <appln_id>myid</appln_id>
                  <password>mypasss</password>
                  <cust_id>1234</cust_id>
               </customer>
             </mainservice>';`

Comment: Replace "$postdata" variable to your one, let me update answer

Comment: You can try above answer, you just need to change the URL here  `file_get_contents('http://example.net/submit.php', false, $context);`  to where you want to send the data

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. `var_dump($result)` is returning `bool(false)`

Comment: Please see the code here `https://www.tehplayground.com/e0934u36dPj5mu4d` . If the call is successful, it will return user authentication error.

Comment: If you have developed api then you should check without authentication and also you need to return only data that posted on your api for testing only.